# (WPF) Copying files "The file is open in another process"

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm making a WPF C# Application and I need to copy a file. As the title says whenever I select any file it says its open in another process, so I'm guessing its something to do with my code.

I've attempted to rewrite the `File.Copy` code to be able to be able to track the progress of the copying.

---

**My file copying code**

```
 public static void CopyFile(string file, string destination, ProgressBar progressCallback)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination)) Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error while creating the resource packs directory " + e.Message, "Canno't create directory", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
        }

        int halfAMeg = (int)(1024 * 1024 * 0.4);

        FileStream strIn = null;
        FileStream strOut = null;

        try
        {
            strIn = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
            strOut = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destination, file), FileMode.Create);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error while copying the file: " + e.Message, "Canno't copy file", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[halfAMeg];
        while (strIn.Position < strIn.Length)
        {
            int len = strIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            strOut.Write(buf, 0, len);

            progressCallback.Maximum = Int32.MaxValue;
            progressCallback.Value = (int)(Int32.MaxValue / (strIn.Position / strIn.Length));
        }
        strIn.Close();
        strOut.Close();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 10/22: This question was made years ago when I greatly underestimated my C++ ability. I apologise for the poor code and poorly written question!**

Comment: Yes, this code is broken, it is not exception-safe.  Lookup the *using* keyword in your favorite C# language book.  And really rather best to stop assuming you can do a better job than File.Copy().

Comment: @HansPassant Why i dont get is that this code worked in a winforms program. Also, is there a way to attach File.Copy() progress to a progress bar?

Comment: It will randomly fail.  Once it fails, it will keep failing since the *strIn* stream wasn't closed and was opened with FileAccess.ReadWrite so cannot be opened again..  Get the pretty progress dialog that is used in Windows by using [FileSystem.CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127966(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant But the point of the custom dialog is so i can add buttons and change the title and stuff. The repo is at https://github.com/TheDiamondYT1/MC10-Editor.